# How can I deploy my telepot bot to Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, bots

I've set up a really simple Telegram Bot with telepot and tried to deploy it to Heroku. Everything's working fine, except the Bot.

Can somebody tell me where the mistake is? I am not quite sure about the Procfile for example.

Git project link: https://github.com/mx-wll/telepot-bot-bob

Comment: problem solved... "heroku run ..." did the job